# Item directly into the home page

Tags: category-products, home

Is there a way to have my items into the home page instead of sub categories?
What I'm trying to achieve is to have an home page filled with my products.
I don't want to separate my products in different categories.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about magento1:

You can add a cms block which does this

```
{{block  type="catalog/product_list" category_id="4"  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

- category_id doesn't need to be defined (then all products are shown)
- category_id can be any id, especially of a category which is deactivated
- you can set `column_count="42"` if you want